# know a thing about something vs. know about something

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What's the difference in meaning between two sentences?

1. None of us knew a thing about driving a horse.
2. None of us knew about driving a horse.

Answer (score 1):

1) none of you people had any idea on how to 'ride' a horse. (driving a horse seems wrong to me.)

2) you had to 'ride' a horse (not drive it) at some point of time/some place but you had no idea that you had to do it.

Comment: Also, drive a horse-drawn carriage.

Answer (score 0):

> None of us knew a thing about driving a horse.

This is likely equivalent to saying "None of us knew *how* to drive a horse."

> None of us knew about driving a horse.

This is means something close to "None of us knew that the activity of horse driving was expected/desired/involved in regards to something", the "something" defined by context/previous conversation.

The first sentence can also mean this, but would be an emphasized way to express it.

Comment: I see. The second one depends on the context. It is a little vague without context. Thank you:)